# Keras - Validation accuracy not matching self-measured accuracy in LSTM?

Tags: python, keras, generator, lstm

After two epochs the validation accuracy of my model shows .30, but when I return the predicted classes using model.predict_generator, and measure the accuracy myself - the accuracy is much lower at about .18.

Why are these methods returning different accuracies? I believe it may be related to my implementation or understanding of timeseriesgenerator.

```html
data_gen_train = sequence.TimeseriesGenerator(X, y_ct, timesteps, sampling_rate=1, stride=1, start_index=0, end_index=len(y), batch_size=batch_size)
data_gen_test = sequence.TimeseriesGenerator(X_ho, y_ho_ct, timesteps, sampling_rate=1, stride=1, start_index=0, end_index=len(y), batch_size=batch_size)

model = Sequential()
model.add(LSTM(20, stateful=True, batch_input_shape=(batch_size, timesteps, data_dim)))
model.add(Dense(9, activation='softmax'))
model.compile(loss='categorical_crossentropy', optimizer= 'Nadam', metrics=['accuracy'])
model.fit_generator(data_gen_train, validation_data=data_gen_test, epochs=epochs, shuffle=False, validation_steps= len(y_ho) //batch_size)
y_pred = model.predict_generator(data_gen_test, steps= len(y_ho)//batch_size)
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iAyUX.png)

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer to my question above. The difference in accuracy measurements was due to the pred and ground truth dataset being shifted relative to each other. Keras' pad_sequences should have been used here to avoid this issue.